# Inventor assembly not displaying appearances correctly in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have an Inventor assembly using one standard Inventor Appearance Library appearance and one custom appearance, saved to a local material library. When I load the viewable in Forge the standard appearance displays correctly but the custom appearance displays as the default (no appearance). Is there a way to use Inventor custom appearances in the Forge viewer?

It’s an assembled piece of woodwork and we need to show the woodgrain in the correct direction for each component. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Model Derivative or Design Automation to generate the SVF?
Does the custom appearance use a texture image? - that's not stored in the Inventor document so make sure you provide that too
Would you be able to provide an absolutely minimal sample document we can use and the steps you follow?

Comment: @AdamNagy we are using design automation to generate the svf. The custom texture was created by taking a standard texture, rotating it 90 degrees, and saving it as a custom. I'm not sure how Inventor manages the files in that case.

Comment: I too am getting inconsistent results. I logged it in our system: TREX-940
I'll get back to you once I know more - not sure when that might be though.

Comment: @AdamNagy while we are waiting for that ticket to be completed, can you assist me with setting the material in the forge viewer instead? I have another stackoverflow question regarding that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585300/apply-custom-appearance-to-individual-model-fragments-in-forge-viewer